# How to find total count of emails (Read/Unread) within a specific date range using Microsoft Graph Mail API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a scenario where I want to find out the total number of emails within a specific date range. I am currently using the [List Messages API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) **(GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages)** and tried specifying the **$count=true** parameter but it is not returning the correct value. I researched on this and found out that the **@odata.count** value for messages is not reliable and has a bug where it fails to report the correct count (Very Strange).

Another option is to explore the [List Mail Folders API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) **(GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders)** which has a **totalItemCount** value that I can use but unfortunately there is no way to specify a date range in this API.

Finally, the most crude option is to use the List Messages API and manually count the number of items returned but obviously it will not be efficient.

Can someone please let me know how this can be achieved in a better way?

**Edit:**
The **$count=true** gives correct value when I get emails inside a specific folder (**/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages**) and not all emails for a user (**/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages**). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: AFAIK, there is a property called createdDateTime you can use to filter the message on your end but not with $filter query parameter as the property createdDateTime cannot be used as of now to filter using query parameters.  Why do you think the /message endpoint gives a different count?

Comment: Hi @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, I haven't tried with createdDateTime but with $filter on receivedDateTime property it works fine. I am not sure why they haven't made it to work with createdDateTime.

The $count=true works when i get emails inside a specific folder (/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/{folder_id}/messages) and not for a user (/users/{user_id}/messages). Again, this is a strange quirk with no clear mention in the documentation. Can you please clear these confusions or point me towards something that I might be missing?

Comment: Is the count more or less in your comparison with original count? You will get even deleted items and clutter folders in your count. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http